# Delete array element and shift the rest of it to the left

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I'm trying to achieve is delete array element by its index and shift the rest of it to the left.

So, deleteshifting, say, 2-nd element of array `['a','b','c','d']` returns array `['a','c','d']`.

I've managed to do that using following code and I'm wondering, whether there's some built-in method (or their combination) around to do that in even more concise manner.

```js
var src = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const delShiftLeft = (arr, index) => arr.slice(0,index).concat(arr.slice(index+1));

console.log(delShiftLeft(src,1));
```

Comment: Do you need to delete one value only? How do you know which values to remove? Will it always be an index, or does it depend on the value?

Comment: use array.splice

Comment: You can use `array.splice` as noted in the answers given. However, notice that this will *mutate* your original array. If you want to return a new array, you need to have a shallow copy first: `var delShiftLeft = [...arr].splice(index, 1)`. This approach use the spread syntax to have a shallow copy, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @ZER0 You can used `slice(0)` to do the same in ES5

Comment: Sure, that's why I said "this approach", there are more :) Actually, just `slice()` should be enough, in E5. You could also use `Array.from` (non in ES5). I just prefer the spread. Nowadays I prefer writing modern javascript since with transpilers such Babel that is not a problem anymore. Of course if transpilers are no go, that's another thing and we definitely need to fallback to older syntax / code style.

Comment: @Valtana If any of the answers have you helped you with your question, you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `splice`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```
arr.splice(index, 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the handy [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method. It accepts the following 3 parameters:

1. The index at which the item(s) should be removed from
2. The amount of items that should be removed (0 is a valid value)
3. (Optional) An array of items in case you want to add new items at that index

So for your case, you just have to do `arr.splice(index, 1)`. Keep in mind that splice will return an array of all the removed elements, rather the changed array.

Here is an example, you can test `splice` with:

```js
var original = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

var removed = document.querySelector("#removed");
var result = document.querySelector("#result");

Object.defineProperty(this, "index", {
  get: function() {
    return +document.querySelector("#index").value;
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(this, "count", {
  get: function() {
    return +document.querySelector("#count").value;
  }
});

document.querySelector("#index").addEventListener("change", calculate);
document.querySelector("#count").addEventListener("change", calculate);

function calculate() {
  var array = original.slice(0);
  var removedArray = array.splice(index, count, "e", "f");
  removed.innerHTML = removedArray.map(toLI).join("");
  result.innerHTML = array.map(toLI).join("");
}

function toLI(text) {
  return "<li>" + text + "</li>";
}

calculate();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="index" value="1" min="0" max="4">
<input type="number" id="count" value="1" min="0" max="4">
<span>Adding ["e", "f"] to list</span>
<br/>
<span>Removed: </span>
<ul id="removed"></ul>
<span>Result: </span>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array's filter method.

```js
var src = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];


console.log(src.filter((e,i)=> i!==1));
```